# How to run one web application that uses dlls with different minor builds?

Tags: c#, dll

I have a CMS that uses one version of Telerik dlls, and have a bunch of user controls that have to be added to this CMS system that use another version of the same dlls. These dlls differ in the minor build.

Is there a way I can get them to work together without running into the dreaded  "Could not load file or assembly located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

I tried adding the [probing element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx), that did not seem to work either, as I run into the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the newer DLLs are backward compatible with the older ones, use assembly redirection to force the references to the older DLLs to load the newer one instead. Then you only need the newer set of DLLs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28VS.71%29.aspx

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to load multiple versions of the same assembly within the same app domain.

Comment: I'll try the binding redirect. I wonder how this is different from using the probing element.

Comment: Changing the probing path tells your app where to look for the assemblies. Redirecting the version bindings tells your app (or in this case, user controls) to load a different version of the assembly than the one it was compiled with.